# Easier method to compute minimal perfect hash?

Tags: hash, perfect-hash

I have smallish(?) sets (ranging in count from 0 to 100) of unsigned 32 bit integers. For a given set, I want to come up with minimal parameters to describe a minimal(istic) perfect hash of the given set. High level of the code I used to experiment with the idea ended up something like:

```
def murmur(key, seed=0x0):
    // Implements 32bit murmur3 hash...
    return theHashedKey

sampleInput = [18874481, 186646817, 201248225, 201248705, 201251025, 201251137, 201251185, 184472337, 186649073, 201248625, 201248721, 201251041, 201251153, 184473505, 186649089, 201248657, 201251009, 201251057, 201251169, 186646818, 201248226, 201248706, 201251026, 201251138, 201251186, 186649074, 201248626, 201248722, 201251042, 201251154, 186649090, 201248658, 201251010, 201251058, 201251170]

for seed in range(11111): // arbitrary upper seed limit
    for modulus in range(10000):
        hashSet = set((murmur(x, seed=seed) % modulus for x in sampleInput))
        if len(hashSet) >= len(allValves):
            print('minimal modulus', modulus, 'for seed', seed)
            break
```

This is just basic pseudo code for a 2 axis brute force search. I add lines by keeping track of the different values, I can find seed and modulus values that give a perfect hash and then select the one with the smallest modulus.

It seems to me that there should be a more elegant/deterministic way to come up with these values? But that's where my math skills overflow.

I'm experimenting in Python right now, but ultimately want to implement something in C on a small embedded platform.

Comment: I would first determine a murmur seed that results in a collision-free set of 32-bit values. Then, with that set, determine the smallest modulus that still yields a collision-free set. The work factor should be additive instead of multiplicative for this algorithm.

Comment: Isn’t that what I’m already doing in the code? I guess algorithmically, I could make sure I don’t have any hash collisions first, before looking for minimal modulus, but that’s still just a brute force loop approach.

Comment: no, you have nested loops, thus the work factor is multiplicative. I'm talking about two loops at the same level. First one determines the seed, second one determines the modulus. Unless you want the absolute minimum modulus across all seeds, which your code doesn't do.

Comment: I see it's an old question, but possibly this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824130/is-it-possible-to-create-a-minimal-perfect-hash-function-without-a-separate-look/55843687#55843687